# Is there any way to configure hibernate Transactions with only annotations from the Jersey API

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, jersey

I want to use something similar to `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` that configures a Transaction. But I want to use only the Jersey API. I would like to have some code that looks like the following:

```java
@Resource
private SessionFactory factory;

private Class<E> entity;

private String tableName;

public DataProvider(Class e) {
    this.entity = e;
    this.tableName = entity.getAnnotation(Table.class).name();
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public E get(final Long ID) {
    return (E)factory.getCurrentSession().get(entity, ID);
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<E> getAll() {
    Session s = factory.getCurrentSession();
    return s.createQuery("FROM " + tableName ).list();
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Just put the above code on the service layer and inject it in the Jersey component. Check this http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/

Comment: Note that I don´t want use spring at all. because I´m dont have a application context xml to cofigure beans